# MySQL Cluster Steps To Recover Data If Catstrophic Failure Occurs

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, clustering, ndbcluster, mysql-cluster

I want to know if a catstrophic failure occurs (like a power outage), and all nodes in MySQL Cluster are shutdown in cluster then data will be lost even though a backup was taken? Or it possible that data can still be retrieved?

If yes, then please tell me how it can be retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Cluster checkpoints and logs in-memory data to disk (assuming you leave the default of checkpointing on). As these are streaming writes, fast HDDs are very efficient to handle this activity. Also, all updates are synchronously replicated between data nodes in a node group, and these can be split across data centers using multi-site clustering:
https://blogs.oracle.com/MySQL/entry/synchronously_replicating_databases_across_data

So there are multiple mechanisms available to protect data

HTH!
Mat

Answer (score 0):

I would advise that you keep at least one node or even part of the cluster into a different datacenter thus allowing for a part of your data to be "alive" as such somewhere else.

The backup is as good as the time taken (assuming restore procedures are in place and tested). During the time that has lapsed since the backup your data are not safe unless you are able to have them live somewhere else.

In any case if such a catastrophic situation occurs, you assume that you keep the backups "elsewhere" in order to restore them ?

If that is the case, then keep a spare node there as well.